# Javascript: get all form keys and values and combine them as javascript object to use with XHR 2 FormData

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I use this little snippet to get form values:

```
myForm = document.forms[1];
email = myForm.elements['email'];
```

however, if I plan to use this with XHR 2's FormData, I have to do this:

```
function sendForm() {
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('email', email);

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', '/server', true);
  xhr.onload = function(e) { ... };

  xhr.send(formData);
}
```

is there any way to get all form data as one javascript object with which I can use FormData with?

Answer (score 2):

Just set the form object as the FormData parameter:

```
function sendForm() {
  var myForm = document.forms[1];
  var formData = new FormData(myForm);

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', '/server', true);
  xhr.onload = function(e) { ... };
  xhr.send(formData);
}
```

Note: it also works with `input type="file"`

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is, store all the information in an array and append them dynamically.

```
var myForm = document.forms[1];
var data = {};
data["email"] = myForm.elements["email"];
data["username"] = myForm.elements["username"];
data["password"] = myForm.elements["password"];
//  ... and so on...
```

now in your send for you can pass the data as argument and append all the data:

```
function sendForm(data) {
  var formData = new FormData();

  for(var i in data) {
    formData.append(i,data[i]);
  }

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', '/server', true);
  xhr.onload = function(e) { ... };

  xhr.send(formData);
}
```